# Number of classes for inception network (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I see that a background class is used as a bonus class. So this class is used in case of not classifying an image in the other classes? In my case, I have a binary problem and I want to understand if an image contains food or not. I need to use 2 classes + 1 background class = 3 classes or only 2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two classes. "Not food" *is* your background class. If you were trying to detect food or dogs, you could have 3 classes: "food", "dog", "neither food nor dog".

Comment: So I should have 2 folders, the one with food and the other with non-food images but in the labels.txt file I should write only food? Because from this text file we get the number that correspond to each class. If I do this I will have 1 for food and 0 for non-food but I don't know if it's absolutely right.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by folders and the text file, but 1 for food and 0 for not food seems like it will work.

Comment: I solved it. I am waiting for the accuracy. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 classes should work for you.

In case you are quickly trying to train a neural net and see if it works for your use case, I have created a demo which will require very less number of training examples per class and will train very quickly. I have hosted it [here](http://demo.nanonets.ai/)

Comment: Thank you but I want to create one by myself! :)